# Rails attr_accessor for non model array elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model which has some non-model attributes for shipping address.

One of the elements is:

```
<%= form_for Checkout.new, url: placeorder_url do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field "shipping[firstname]", value: nil, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'First Name' %>
<% end %>
```

the output is

```
<input value="" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" type="text" name="checkout[shipping[firstname]]" id="checkout_shipping[firstname]">
```

But When adding validation for the same in Model, I need to first add it to the **attr_accessor**, which I am unable to do. The model name is Checkout, thats why the checkout in the output html.

The model is:

```
class Checkout
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :shipping

  validates "shipping[firstname]", presence: true
end
```

The posted data is like:

```
{"checkout"=>
 {"shipping"=>
  {
    "firstname"=>"", "lastname"=>"", "companyname"=>"", "address1"=>"",    "address2"=>"", "city"=>"", "state"=>"", "postalcode"=>"", "primaryphone"=>"", "secondaryphone"=>""
  }
 }
}
```

Does anybody have any idea how to allow custom array fields for attr_accessor or any other way to validate the same.

The error I get is:

```
undefined method `shipping[firstname]' for #<Checkout:0x00000001789de8>
```

Comment: name is incorrect `checkout[shipping[firstname]]` it should be `checkout[shipping][firstname]`

Comment: and you will need to create attr accessor with first name and assign it with `params[checkout][shipping][firstname]`

Comment: @DeepakMahakale Hi Deepak, but what to write to make the same, f.text_field "shipping[firstname]", value: nil, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'First Name'

Comment: f.text_field "[shipping][firstname]" and  f.text_field "checkout[shipping][firstname]", it did not come out as checkout[shipping][firstname]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add attr_accessor for firstname

```
class Checkout
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :firstname
end
```

And then you can use it as an attribute. Make use of `name` to generate proper element name

```
 <%= f.text_field :firstname, value: nil,name: 'checkout[shipping][firstname]', class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'First Name' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your name must be checkout[shipping][firstname], and not checkout[shipping[firstname]], as mentioned in the comments.
One way to fix this would be like so:

```
<%= form_for Checkout.new, url: placeorder_url do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field "shipping[firstname]", name: "checkout[shipping][firstname]", value: nil, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'First Name' %>
<% end %>
```